# PayPal like IPN with Google Checkout

Tags: php, web-services, paypal, paypal-ipn, google-checkout

I've reading the Google Checkout docs but I haven't found anything similar to PayPal IPN for Google Checkout.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to automatically process orders using Google Checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Google Docs.](http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=25397)

> Processing orders automatically
>
> If you're using the Google Checkout API, you can also process orders systematically. Review ['Order Processing API'](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/index.html#order_processing_api) in the Developer's Guide for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at :
http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Notification_API.html

And a sample PHP response script :
http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP_ResponseHandler.htm